# How to get text from this Html on webbrowser? [VB.NET]

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to parse this HTML code:

```
<textarea id="1" name="padText" class="col-xs-12 text-tab-1" style="min-height: 400px; height: 493px;">TEXT</textarea>
```

And I'm trying to use many codes.
This one is one of them :

```
 Dim MailElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("1")

    If MailElement IsNot Nothing Then 'Necessary check: Was the element found?
        RichTextBox1.Text = MailElement.GetAttribute("value")
    End If
End Sub
```

But unfortunately is not working.
I've tried to parse the textarea ID too, but it gives me back  a simple "0".

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `MailElement.Value`?

Comment: Before HTML 5, an ID attribute had to start with a letter, so `id="1"` was not valid. That might explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("padText").GetAttribute("value")
```